# How can I open a new activity on an expandable listview clicked

Tags: android-listview

How can I open a new activity on an expandable listview clicked
Am really desperate I need help I have been searching for months. I will be very glad if anyone helps.

Comment: "for months". Are you sure?

Answer (score 0):

New activities in Android can be started using [Intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).

Now, it depends entirely on your ExpandableListView to decide which activity is opened. For instance, if the position is a factor, then you can do something like:

```
yourExpandableListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

             if(position == 1){
                 startActivity(new Intent(this, FirstActivity.class);
             }else{
                 startActivity(new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
             }


        }
});
```

Comment: the intent gets underlined i mean this  (new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class)

Comment: Obviously, you're supposed to replace SecondActivity with your Activity. Alright, see I think you should first learn Android first.

Comment: I NOE THAT BUT STILL UNDERLINED GUESS IS THE POSITION OF THE METHOD